# Difference between Constantize in rails and Constant in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I come across Constantize internal function of Rails which Tries to find a constant with the name specified in the argument string.

The function uses const_get function of ruby in its definition can anyone tell what is the difference between two as i am not able to find out any difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`String#constantize` can find nested constants (classes and modules). `const_get` can be used to find a single constant within a module / class / top-namespace. You'll have to use a combination of `const_get` and `const_defined?` recursively to mimic the functionality of `constantize`